# Network speed varies greatly

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, internet-speed, windows-10-pro

My WiFi speed tests have been reporting very [low](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI1M1.jpg) figures as of yesterday. Also, as you can see in the very low-res videos, google loads a white page for a second or two before loading the full site, unlike bing.

I am running Windows 10 Pro that I activated yesterday, and it was immediately after activation that these issues popped up.

I've run Win10's built in troubleshooter, Kaspersky, Windows Defender, and restarted several times. Also, I reset and reinstalled my network drivers using a built in function whose name escapes me at the moment.

Ethernet is not available to me at the moment.

What can I do about this?

Comment: If you are in the USA and live near or in certain metropolis areas, you are experiencing a general internet slowdown, due to an increase in work-at-home employees, as well as an increase in unemployed people and more youths out of school. The above comment is made based on an article in my local newspaper and not of research, hence a comment in place of an answer.

Comment: I just did some more snooping, and found that yahoo.com searches don't work at all, and there's some weird stuff in the console when I inspect element.